# Polymorphism in TypeScript: Lenient type

Tags: typescript, polymorphism

I have a question about polymorphism in Typescript. Plz look at the code below:

```js
type A = { a: 'a' };
type B = { b: 'b' };

interface Lib {
    method(arg: A): void;
    method(arg: B): void;
}
declare const lib: Lib;

type C = A | B;
declare const c: C;

lib.method(c); // error

'a' in c 
  ? lib.method(c) // no error
  : lib.method(c); // no error either
```

As you can see we cannot just call `lib.method(c)` even though it'd be okay. Because TS doesn't compare my argument with a combined function signature. It checks subsequently it with each of overloads. But when I split my value into several simpler pieces - it works well.

But... doesn't my working code like `... ? fn(c) : fn(c)` look completely idiotically? :-)

So the question is - how to handle such cases? I faced it in `react-router` with their `push` method. I see only next solutions:

1. Override their overloaded type with a new one that would be more lenient
2. Write code like `... ? fn(c) : fn(c)` everywhere
3. Write my own wrapper with my own signature
4. `fn(c as unknown as any)`

Are there anything better? :) What's the root of the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107

Comment: Thank you. That's it. And what's funny - `kirillku` there wrote about the exact my case (`push in history`) :-)

Comment: I think the "best" way of handling it would be a third overload which accepts the union of other overloads params, but since you're not controlling the library I would just wrap those overloads in your own function

Comment: Yeah, I overrode it in my `override.d.ts` :) It's not the only type\interface that should be altered in our project.

Comment: Is there any way I can mark your 1st comment as a correct answer?

Comment: You can write comment yourself and accept it, so other people can see the conclusion

Answer (score 1):

As @ritaj wrote above - it's wellknown issue in TS community. The main discussion is there: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107

There's no optimal solution now. So I used the most convenient for me - I have overridden the broken interface adding a more wide type.